# Excel Solver slow due to second workbook

Tags: vba, excel, solver

I've noticed something new today that will cause me problems in the future regarding Excel's Solver, so I want to get a jump on it.

I'm using VBA to sequentially apply solver moving down a sheet (let's say this sheet belongs to 'workbook 1'). This all works fine and I'm happy with the results of Solver. Yay... My concern is this: When I have a second rather large workbook open (let's call this 'workbook 2'), WHICH HAS ABOSOLUTELY NO LINKS TO MY CURRENT WORKBOOK, Solver takes around 20 times as long to run.

Naturally the most reasonable thing to do is not have 'workbook 2' open when Solver is running. For now that's my solution, however, in the very near future I will need to have both workbooks open simultaneously. So I pose the following question:

Why would solver take longer to run with two books open even though it's not even touching one of them?

In case skeptics are concerned that my code is doing something unusual here it is:

```
Sub ExampleSeqSolver()
Dim Iter As Long
Dim Time0 As Double
Dim Duration As Double

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
' Solver requires that it is working on the 'active sheet', silly but w/e
Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
' watch optimization efficiency
Time0 = Timer

For Iter = 2 To 13

    ' my data are sometimes related to adjacent rows so I was considering supplying an initial solution to reduce the number of runs
    ' Sheets("Sheet1").Range("$AC$" & ITER & ":$AI$" & ITER) = _
    ' Sheets("Sheet1").Range("$AC$" & ITER - 1 & ":$AI$" & ITER - 1)

    If Cells(Iter, 1) <> 0 Then
        SolverReset
        SolverOptions AssumeNonNeg:=True, Iterations:=100
        SolverAdd CellRef:="$AK" & Iter, Relation:=2, FormulaText:="1"
        SolverOK SetCell:="$AW$" & Iter, MaxMinVal:="2", ByChange:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("$AC$" & Iter & ":$AI$" & Iter), Engine:=1
        SolverSolve True
    End If

Next Iter

' report optimization duration
Duration = Round(Timer - Time0, 2)
MsgBox "Optimization finished in " & Duration & " seconds", vbInformation
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tested to see what effect setting `Application.Calculation` to `xlCalculationManual` has?  (I **think** Solver will force a calculation of the active sheet even if the overall calculation method is "Manual".)

Comment: "Why would solver take longer to run with two books open even though it's not even touching one of them?" > Likely because you do not have enough RAM/Memory, also the issue with 32-bit software these days.

Comment: @YowE3K Good thought! I was thinking the same thing. At first hesitant to try since I was concerned that my objective function would not update. Gave it a shot, no change. I think that calculation method might always be handled at the application level (even if solver is controlling it. i.e., everything is being set back to automatic). Good thought though, thanks!

Comment: @KDavis, it's possible. Forgive my ignorance regarding memory allocation, but if I look in taskmanager, I have ~4G free and Excel is only using ~200,000 K. Should this mean I'm not pressing up against system or 32-bit application limits?

Answer (score 0):

The presence of 'workbook 2' is correlated but not causal.  In my case there is one particular workbook that causes the solver slowdown; most others don't.  The workbook that causes the slowdown is about 4mb.  Much larger workbooks do not cause a slowdown.  The one causing the slowdown does not to the best of my knowledge contain either macros or VB. I recommend that this problem be shown to Frontline systems who developed the original solver.